# what's the fastest way to import array data and save the array data with specific format?

Tags: julia

I have approximately 1000 pieces of simulation data which have 2D array and size of the array is 1000(Row), 7(Col).

First, I tried to import and export the array just to see calculating speed and I programmed as below.

Input data structure

```
SIMULATION RESULTS
 0.599566E+00 0.666925E-06   0.3348E+02   0.2527E+03  -0.6948E+04  ...
 0.599633E+00 0.666924E-06   0.3394E+02   0.2529E+03  -0.6949E+04  ...
 0.599699E+00 0.666922E-06   0.3424E+02   0.2528E+03  -0.6949E+04  ...
 0.599766E+00 0.666920E-06   0.3440E+02   0.2527E+03  -0.6949E+04  ...
 0.599833E+00 0.666919E-06   0.3460E+02   0.2525E+03  -0.6948E+04  ...
 0.599899E+00 0.666919E-06   0.3488E+02   0.2522E+03  -0.6948E+04  ...
 0.599966E+00 0.666919E-06   0.3530E+02   0.2520E+03  -0.6948E+04  ...
.
.
.
```

first try

```
using Glob
filename = glob("*.dat*")
for i in filename
    data = readdlm(i, Float64, skipstart=1)
    writedlm("new_"*i, data)
end
close(data)
```

second try to keep specific format

```
using Glob
filename = glob("*.dat*")
for i in filename
    data = readdlm(i, Float64, skipstart=1)
    m = (a->(@sprintf "%15.3f" a)).(data)
    writedlm("new_"*i, m, "" , quotes=false)
end
close(data)
```

But the problem is that the calculating speed is very slow.

So, Please give me some advises so that I can deal with array data much faster (let me know if I don't

follow the Julia style and teach me some better way please.)

Comment: why is this tagged `python`

Comment: Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Don't know about Julia, but in python you can use the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) module to measure the execution time. Anyway - yeah, python is not quite fast; you either have to accept this or use some other tool for the task. Additionally, there are many factors determining your runtime, for example as you're reading data: You can't solve a slow HDD with a fast programming language.

Comment: *"Julia was much faster than python"* : this sentences is to general to be true. Pure Python code with loops is indeed often slower than the same in Julia because of the JIT, but for Numpy calls this is not always true. As for IO-bounded operations like in your case, the two will likely be equally fast. If you load data from a fast SSD, you could try to parallelize the loop (some SSD can read data faster in parallel).

Comment: If you need more low-level code have a look at `Printf.format(stdout, Printf.format"%15.3f", 3.5)` . Of course replace `stdout` with your stream and replace `3.5` with whatever `Float64` value you have. This will avoid materializing `String`s and should be much faster - you will avoid lots of garbage collection. Still `DelimitedFiles` or `CSV.jl` will have better throughout optimization.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't be writing this manually. Try to use the extremely efficient CSV.jl package to read/write delimited files:

```
using DataFrames
using CSV

# read from disk
df = CSV.read("fname.dat", DataFrame, [options go here])

# do your calculations
df.result = df.column1 + df.column2

# write to disk
CSV.write("new.dat", df)
```

CSV.jl is the fastest reader/writer of delimited files across all popular languages. For more information read this old blog post: https://juliacomputing.com/blog/2020/06/fast-csv

And to correct a comment above that IO speed is similar in Julia and Python, the CSV.jl implementation beats Python's pandas by a factor of 10x to 20x.

Comment: as far as I understand Kwon wants to apply `printf` formatting of floats before saving them. and that is the problem here - I do not see any `Float64` formatting options for `CSV`.

Comment: You are correct, it seems that he also wants to keep a specific format for the strings. Your comment in the other thread above is a good direction for him. Thanks.